# Javascript load external frameworks after onReady

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Usually you have all your frameworks (scripts and css) in your head element on your HTML source code and while rendering the page they will be loaded.
E.g. I want to load jQuery and boostrap it would look something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="jquery.min.css"\>
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css"\>
  </head>
</html>
```

But imagine a situation where you have only jQuery loaded from the beginning and you want to perform a action like clicking on a button and need some framework functionalities like something that bootstrap offers, they would need to be loaded right after the click.

In my understanding that is not as easy as it sounds since the framework which needs to be loaded after the side was already rendered needs to perform an OnReady call. Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Kind regards,
Marius

Comment: the best practice is for scripts to go at the end of the body tag, not in the head

Comment: You can trigger those calls manually like `$(document).trigger('ready')`

Comment: Package a views/page required files into a bundle and load that? Would the use of `RequireJs` help? Is there a concrete question? Or an example you can write up to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: jQuery has a method called `$.getScript(path, callback)`. You can use that to do what you are looking for. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/. You could make something similiar for the CSS, appending it to the head and giving a little timeout to ensure the loading.

Comment: `In my understanding that is not as easy as it sounds` - First SO I came across looking for `load JavaScript after click` ► [**loading javascript file after jquery.ready**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993748/load-javascript-file-after-button-click)

Comment: unfortunately that is not working for me https://jsfiddle.net/uvyetrcb/2/

Comment: A +1 as this is an important topic when dealing with page speeds and async  loading of scripts.

Answer (score 0):

"imagine a situation where you have only jQuery loaded from the beginning and you want to perform a action like clicking on a button and need some framework functionalities like something that bootstrap offers, they would need to be loaded right after the click."

What you are describing is [lazy loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) of dependencies.

[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) does this very well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking to do this to speed up the user's page load performance you can simply use the async property of the the  tag like so:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" async></script>
```

Read more about async loading at https://css-tricks.com/thinking-async/

If you have other reasons to load js after a certain event then use the following approach:

```
function loadJavaScript(url)
{
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('src', url);
    s.setAttribute('async',true);
    document.head.appendChild(s);
}
```

you can pass the address of the script as `loadJavaScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.2/dojo/dojo.js')`

**UPDATE**

Using the onload handler to call a function when the script loads:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#test').click(function() {
   console.log("oO");
    loadCss('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    loadJavaScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.js',function(){
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    });
  });
});


function loadCss(url,fn) {
    var link = document.createElement("link");
    link.type = "text/css";
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
}

function loadJavaScript(url)
{
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('src', url);
    s.setAttribute('async',false);
    if(typeof(fn) == "function")
    {
      fn();
    }
    document.head.appendChild(s);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Basic</button>
<select class="selectpicker">
<option>1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast answer, unfortunately this is not working for me, i did a small testcase: https://jsfiddle.net/uvyetrcb/1/

Comment: @marius I got your concern so in that case you will have to use the onload handler let me update the answer for you.

Comment: unfortunately still not :/ the command $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh'); usually should change the apperiance of the select field once called, in this example it doesnt, its part of the bootstrap-select framework